# How to make a nested for loop by plotting two different data sets side by side?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I have these two different data sets (with the same shape) [data1 and data2], and I want to plot the first index of data1 next to the first index of data2:

So figure of data1[0] next to figure of data2[0], figure of data1[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EUVB.png) next to figure of data2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EUVB.png), etc. so 32 plots rather than just 16

I tried doing a nested for loop, but it is only plotting data2, rather than data1 and data2 together. What might be wrong the for loop?

Example and reproducible code is below:

```
data1 = np.random.rand(16, 20, 15)
data2 = np.random.rand(16,20,15)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=4, figsize=(10,20))
for i,ax in zip(range(16), axes.ravel()):
    for j,ax in zip(range(16),axes.ravel()):
        x = ax.contourf(data1[i],levels=10, extend='both')
        y = ax.contourf(data2[i],levels=10,extend='both')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: small part of plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=4, figsize=(10,20))
axes = axes.ravel()

# plot the data in pairs
for i in range(16):
    axes[2*i].contourf(data1[i],levels=10, extend='both')
    axes[2*i].set_title(f'data1[{i}]')
    axes[2*i+1].contourf(data2[i],levels=10,extend='both')
    axes[2*i+1].set_title(f'data2[{i}]')

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]